# Route requests with query parameters in Django without prepending with a backslash

Tags: regex, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to process requests that have query parameters similar to the following url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo?bar=-capacity. I've done quite a bit of trial and error with Django's url patterns and regex but no success so far. My regex knowledge is admittedly lite.

This pattern **url(r'^foo(.*)$', views.QueryFoo.as_view()),** will process the above request but the problem is it grabs regular get requests like the following: **http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo**. I can add a backslash to the url pattern like this **url(r'^foo/(.*)$', views.QueryFoo.as_view()),** which seems to be the Django norm but then I have to handle get requests from two separate urls.

Edit:
One other idea would be to route all requests to /foo to the the same view and then check for a query parameter in the url. If it exists process it otherwise do normal get request processing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a good question, but I'd say the behavior you've found is probably what most people want. I'd probably adjust my code to it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Django URL/view matching only applies to the path part of the URL, always excluding the query string parameters. So by definition there is no way to make it match two different views, depending on the presence (or not) of certain query string parameters.

If you want to do a different thing depending on if parameters were passed on a querystring, do something like:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.GET:  # query string parameters were passed
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```